# Override executeCreate action in admin generator module

Tags: symfony1, admin-generator

One feature of the current project where I am working, is to send an email notification with some information about the recent created object.

Here is the code of my current action code:

```
public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request)
 {
  try 
  {
   parent::executeCreate($request);
  }
  catch (sfStopException $e)
  {
   $this->notifyAdmin($request);

   throw new sfStopException();
  }
 }
```

On the past, the previous code already worked fine but now it does not. I do not quite understand the possible cause, once the project were it was used, is connected to a symfony release tag (1_4_4) and I assume that no changes were made. Now, the code of the catch block is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted only sends a notification if the create proces fails.

To notify the admin everytime, move the notification below the create call.

```
   parent::executeCreate($request);
   $this->notifyAdmin($request);
```

Comment: I had already tested the solution you purposed. All the instruction placed bellow the call of the parent method, aren't executed.